# How to install pry/pry-rails globally for all projects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pry, pry-rails

How can replace `irb` and `rails console` with `pry/pry-console` globally for every project without having to include it in a project?

Comment: Eh. Install it globally and call `pry` instead of `irb`. I doubt it would be possible to get into `pry` shell session from the code by calling `binding.pry` without the respective gemset to be explicitly installing `pry`.

Answer (score 1):

Easy mode is to hack your `.irbrc`, so that when anything tries to load IRB, you take over and force it to load Pry instead:

```
begin
  gem "pry"
rescue => ex
  $stderr.puts ex.message
else
  require "pry"
  Pry.start
  exit!
end
```

If you're using Bundler, however, that'll still only work if Pry is available in the current bundle.

---

To make it work even when Bundler doesn't think Pry should be allowed to activate, you'll need to monkey with gem loading -- Bundler tries very hard to make it impossible.

To do that, you'll need a `~/.rubyrc.rb` file, which you ensure always gets loaded for all ruby commands by exporting `RUBYOPT=$HOME/.rubyrc` in your `.bashrc` / `.zshrc`.

That file can then hack into Bundler's internals to force loading a non-bundled gem. You can also monkey-patch `Bundler.require`, which is how Rails loads all the gems in the Gemfile, to similarly force `pry-rails` in any application that contains `rails`.

(This strategy also allows you to globally support `binding.pry`, without needing to explicitly require anything, or add the gem to the project.)

Comment: Any additional info on the additional hacks needed? Does this work for the current pry-rails?